# How to highlight a table row of a TableViewer with a custom color

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I'm using Viewer Framework in my Eclipse RCP Application,wherein my table has all the capabilities like sorting and filtering,the problem is with,when i select a row in the table it gets highlighted in blue color by default, when a user try to filter using search box provided,which is located above the table,then the previously selected row gets faded away.To overcome this i thought it would be better to have a custom color or predefined color like red and which doesn't get faded away even Table-viewer loses focus(i don't know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you're running under Windows 7, where this is the defined behavior of table selection and the focus. Just try to select a file in the explorer and then focus on another window....

Almost the same behavior is seen under various versions of OSX, and possibly for other operating systems as well.

Can you work around it? Yes, but it will require some work with a `SWT.ItemPaint` listener...